# Recursive Vue 3 component doesn't update props

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, recursion

I have two recursive components. The first is the wrapper of the elements, the second, respectively, by the element itself

The wrapper

```
<template>
  <div class="filter-tree">
    <filter-tree-item
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item.id"
      :deep="deep"
      :item="item"
      @on-interact="interact"
    ></filter-tree-item>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
export interface Props {
  items: Items[];
  deep?: number;
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  deep: 0
})

const interact = () => {
  console.log(props.deep) // logs always 0
}
</script>
```

The item

```
<template>
  <p @click="handle">{{ deep }}</p> <!--Shows correct deep-->
  <filter-tree v-if="hasChildren" :items="item.children" :deep="deep + 1"></filter-tree>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
export interface Props {
  item: Item;
  deep?: number;
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  deep: 0,
});

const emits = defineEmits(['on-interact'])

const handle = () => {
  emits('on-interact')
}
</script>
```

The deep prop is output correctly in the template, but when I try to get it inside my script, I always get the topmost one, in my case 0. Although 2 came out and I should have gotten 2.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that way, see this example, it will works:

```
const emits = defineEmits<{ (event: 'on-interact', deep: number): void }>();

const handle = () => {
  emits('on-interact', props.deep)
}
```

see the documentation here
https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features